# To get nth prime number

Tags: python

Given the value of n, print the n'th prime number.

Input : A single integer n.
Output : A single number which is the n'th prime number.

```
n=int(input())
l=[]
c=0
for i in range(1,10001):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        if i%j==0:
            c=c+1
    if c==2:
        c=0
        l.append(i)
    else:
        c=0
print(l[n-1])
```

how the above code works to get the nth prime number

Answer (score 0):

a prime number can only be divided by 1 and itself, so there are only two number such that `i%j==0`, if `c=2` i is a prime number. We add it to the list and return `l[n-1]` which correspond to the nth prime number.

But the code can easily be improved to be faster

Comment: Actually, the code returns `l[n-1]` because list indexes in python are zero based. The reason this code will not mark 1 as prime is because only one modulo operation gives 0 for 1.

Comment: indeed, my bad :)